# How to plot the histogram of a volume using imhist in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, tiff, histogram

I have array of TIFF images. I have stacked them to make a volume. How can I plot the histogram of the volume in MATLAB? The function "imhist" expects its input to be two-dimensional.

I have also tried to plot the histogram of individual TIFFs and consolidate, but in vain.

Here is the code I tried to consolidate the histograms:

```
counter = 0;
for i = 1:numel(image_files)
    [count, x] = imhist(vol(:,:,i));
    counter = count + counter
end;
```

Is/are there any other ways I could plot the histogram of a volume in MATLAB?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`imhist` also accepts one-dimensional input. Thus, you can reshape your volume into a vector, and call `imhist` like this:

```
imhist(volume(:))
```

Comment: Thanks for the very simple logic, Jonas. I tried the following: `frequency_Occur = 0; nbins = 2^16;
for kk = 1:numel(image_files)
    [counter, graylevel] = imhist(vol(:,:,kk), nbins);
    frequency_Occur = frequency_Occur + counter;
end;
plot(frequency_Occur);`